# Data gathering and selling

Tags: control, arduino, sensors, matlab, robotics-toolbox

a friend of mine is building various Robots with different structures, sensors,  limbs  executing different tasks. He gathers data from all sensors etc regarding technical and scientific range of subjects. He is asking if there is somewhere where he can sell those data. He can provide raw data as well. Does anyone know if there such a thing or service?

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here

Comment: I am really sorry @jsotola,  I did not know, it won't happen again.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Juljan Haka, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.